# Apply windows theme to winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, themes

I currently have an application for personal use, which I also take to work. I use a custom windows 8 theme on my computer at home and my application is designed around this theme. So when I open my application at work, or anywhere else for that matter, it obviously looks nothing like expected and certain text is unreadable because the colors simply do not match.

My question is, if there's a library or feature which I've missed, with which I can apply this windows theme to my application without installing the theme on the system?

If not, is this possible with WPF, without too much trouble?

Thanks!

Comment: How does your theme affect your application (I'm curious)? I get the feeling for colours you are using the options for "windows" colours, you could always just use the actual colours instead of those labelled as windows colours

Comment: If you use [SystemColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.aspx) to define the color scheme of your app then it should match your current windows theme and I think it will change when the windows theme is changed.  Sounds like you haven't used the `SystemColors` throughout your app (maybe the reason why some of your text becomes unreadable is because some parts of your app are using `SystemColors`, e.g. backgrounds, and other parts are not using `SystemColors`, e.g. text color).

Comment: I just looked up how the system colors actually work, thank you guys. Lesson well learned. I thought it was just a color scheme of default windows applications, didn't know it was actually tied to the theme. However, my theme also uses custom control styles. Which are still not transferable. So my question still stands.

Comment: What custom control styles? could you elaborate more? It sounds difficult without installing dependencies..

Comment: Here's an example of a custom windows theme. http://virtualcustoms.net/showthread.php/58619-HUD-Evolution-For-Windows-8-8-1 You install it and it'll modify the style of all your windows controls and elements. I installed it and made my windows and it's application look great, I was just wondering if the same thing could be done but to my application only. If it doesn't sound familiar it probably does not exist.